# Reactjs v17.0.2 showing blank white screen on chrome browser but its completely fine on firefox browser

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router-dom

I am using Webpack as my module bundler for my Reactjs application. Using spring boot as a backend service. It's completely fine on the Firefox browser both in the development and production server. You can check the production version from here:
[https://fullstackapp.io](https://www.fullstackapp.io)

But it's not working on chrome browser its showing completely a blank white page like this both in the production and development environment. How can I overcome with this situation?

My **wepback.config.js** is:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: "/src/index.jsx",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: "bundle.js",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ["babel-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|ico|ttf|eot|woff)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ["file-loader"]
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".jsx", ".js"]
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        static: {
            directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        },
        hot: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://localhost:8080',
                secure: false
            }
        },

    },
    watchOptions: {
        ignored: /node_modules/
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            hash: true,
            title: "Hot Module Replacement",
            template: "/public/index.html"
        })
    ]
}
```

**Showing error:**
[image]

Comment: There is indicator "1error" but error itself seems to be filtered out

Comment: it's just a RestAPI response. it just checking if a user is authenticated or not.

Comment: just opened your link in chrome. Renders fine. No errors.

Comment: please add some reproducible code, it is hard for people to work with minified code.

Comment: Sometimes it's work in Chrome but not always when you do hard reload on browser. Please check with mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my problem. The problem is actually happened because of this code which I wrote in my App.js file. I removed it and it works.

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.onload = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setPageLoad(false);
        }, 30);
    }
    window.addEventListener("popstate", () => {
        setPageLoad(true);
        window.location.reload();
    })
},[])
```

I used it because, I need some times to set my route when user use browser hard reload or navigate backward or forward using browser button. I removed it and solved it in another way. And now it's working completely fine.